# How to handle a single form to update multiple unrelated models?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I am working on a legacy Rails 3.2 application that has a lot of settings a user can manage. Settings are associated with 3 types of model in the system: `User`, `Company` and `CompanyUser`. In order to avoid having to write database migrations each time a new type of setting is added
I've essentially created a key/value store (1 row for each setting) that has a polymorphic association with each of the above mentioned models. A base `Setting` class handles all of the common functionality like setting the key, relationships etc. each type of setting extends the base class and can contain it's own validation and/or logic. For example:

```
class Settings::EmailSignature < Setting
  validates :whatever
end
```

For any model that requires a setting I've implemented a `has_setting` helper method that sets up the association and provides some delegates to directly get and set the setting without needing to go via the associated model object, the `User` model might look like:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_setting :email_signature
end
```

This side of the code is working well, however the problem I have is when I create the form for the settings. For the user it might make sense to have User, Company and CompanyUser settings mixed together in the same form. Using nested attributes doesn't feel like a good solution in this situation as the settings are not related and there is no common parent object. I've considered using a form object to handle mapping each setting to the correct object but that doesn't feel like a great option either as each setting would require knowing it's id, the associated records id and it's type. This would not be particularly easy to manage when building the form.

I'm about to go down the route of having each setting in it's own form and having the record save automatically as the user edits each item. This would mean only a single record is ever saved at a time and will make things much simpler at the controller layer and also provide a lot of flexibility in how settings a grouped. Before I go down this route I wanted to see if there are any other options for submitting a single form in a single transaction that I may have overlooked?

Please note, this application is written in Rails 3.2 and is not in a state in which it can be easily upgraded to Rails 4 right now so any solutions need to work with Rails 3.2.

Comment: https://blog.pivotal.io/labs/labs/form-backing-objects-for-fun-and-profit.  This is the pattern I prefer(presenter pattern).

Comment: @ruby_newbie this is the same as the "form object" I am talking about, I can't see a way to use this without needing to pass in lots of additional information in order for the object to work out what record each param relates to. There is also the added complication of access control which a Form Object does not help with solving when dealing with multiple unrelated models.